# Correct descriptions of REST HTTP actions?

Tags: web-services, http, rest

Having read numerous websites that define various interpretations of GET/POST/PUT/DELETE I am left somewhat confused. After thorough reading I believe that I now understand but it would be useful if somebody could confirm whether I am on the right track or not.

The following explains my understanding of REST actions:

```
GET    - get data
POST   - create or update **entire or part** resource at non-specific entity URI
PUT    - create or update **entire** resource at specific entity URI
DELETE - delete entity at specific entity URI
```

Some examples of REST URIs:

```
/api/user
    POST   - create a new user and respond with unique user ID

/api/user/{id}
    GET    - get data for specific user
    POST   - update some or all user data
    PUT    - create or replace entire user
    DELETE - delete specific user

/api/user/{id}/profile
    GET    - get data for user profile
    POST   - update some or all user profile data
    PUT    - create or replace entire user profile

/api/users
    GET    - perform query to retrieve listing of user data
```

Am I along the right lines? is there anything important that I should know / read?

Comment: REST is basically what you've described, it doesn't really have a standard as much as it is a hand-wavy-thing where HTTP methods do what they were intended to do in the spec, and URIs are semantically logical.

Comment: Agreed with Incognito. You've got it figured out already. Go forth and RESTify.

Comment: However, it does look like you're imposing a hard-coded URI structure and requiring clients of your API to become dependent on the exact format of all of your URIs. Instead, just have a single entry-point or "Cool" URI (let's say /api in your case) and have clients navigate to the sub-resources through a traversal of the returned payload data ("media types"). That way, you'll be free to evolve your URIs later without forcing your clients to change too. That's "HATEOAS" and it's a huge benefit of REST.

Comment: Hello @Brian, I haven't come across the hypermedia constraint before and have been reading about it. I can see how explicitly referencing URIs for things like pagination could work, but I do not understand how developers could consume a single entry point. If a consumer of my API wanted to design a custom profile editor (just to follow from my example) then how would they access an equivalent of `POST /api/user/24/profile` via the "Cool" URI `/api`? cheers